# What exactly causes dry skin to itch?

Tags: dermatology, itching, oil-of-skin, dry-skin

I know that dry skin can itch (since I'm almost sure I have it), but why? I don't really know anything about dermatology (or medicine generally) so the best hypothesis I can come up with is that nerves in the skin are left more sensitive due to a lack of coating from natural skin oil such that even regular sensations such as sweating or contact with airborne particles are perceived more intensely. Or perhaps airborne particles are more easily embedded deeper in the skin due to lack of coating, thereby mixing with sweat and clogging pores more easily (potentially resulting in acne, as well). May anybody with knowledge in this subject please inform me? Thank you in advance.